# How to create a default screen before oncreate method

Tags: android

Hey i am creating a app that is pretty much heavy...It works fine but when i am moving from one activity to another then a completely black screen stays for some time then the activity loads..Now I want to make a default screen that shows a loading message before the activity loads..otherwise user thought that the app is hang or crash...

```
public class TenderViewActivity extends ListActivity {

int[] pos={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
public static DefaultHttpClient client;
private static final String DEFAULT = "N/A";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mobile.bidnemo.MESSAGE";
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.mobile.bidnemo.MESSAGE2";
JSONArray jArray;
ArrayList<Spanned> list = new ArrayList<Spanned>();  
int starting_point=0;
int limit=50;
String cat;
String tender_name;
String title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bid_backgrounds);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Intent intent = getIntent();
cat = intent.getStringExtra(BidActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE4);
tender_name = intent.getStringExtra(BidActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE3);
title=intent.getStringExtra(BidActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE5);
setTitle(title);

ArrayList<Spanned> tenders=tenderlist(cat,tender_name);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this,R.layout.tender_listing,R.id.basic_details,tenders));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
String resid=returnid(pos[position]);
Intent detailsTender=new Intent(this,DetailsTenderActivity.class);
detailsTender.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, resid);
startActivity(detailsTender);
Toast.makeText(this ,"You selected tender: "+resid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public ArrayList<Spanned> tenderlist(String cat, String name){
/***Tender view process begin***/
Spanned s;
String active="";
try {
StrictMode.enableDefaults();                    
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("cat", cat);
json.put("srch_str", name);

client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String url = "https://www.myserver.com/index.php";
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
request.setHeader("json", json.toString());
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null){
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
String result="";
try{
 BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream,"iso-8859-1"),8); 
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
String line=null;
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
sb.append(line+"\n");
}
instream.close();
result= sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){}
jArray= new JSONArray(result);
for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject getjson=jArray.getJSONObject(i);

String tender_id=getjson.getString("tender_id");
String tender_title=getjson.getString("tender_title");
String start_date=getjson.getString("tender_additional_info_bid_sub_start_date");
String end_date=getjson.getString("tender_additional_info_bid_sub_end_date");

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date date= df.parse(end_date);     

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date current_date=(c.getTime());

if(current_date.compareTo(date)<=0){ active="active"; }else{ active="inactive"; }

if("active".equals(active)){ 
s=Html.fromHtml(                "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> ID: </font>"          +tender_id+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> Title: </font>"       +tender_title+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> Posting date: </font>"+start_date+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> Ending date: </font>" +end_date+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#25C31F'>"                      +active+ 
                            "</font><br>"); 
                }else{
                s=Html.fromHtml(
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> ID: </font>"          +tender_id+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> Title: </font>"       +tender_title+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> Posting date: </font>"+start_date+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#232322'> Ending date: </font>" +end_date+
                            "&nbsp;<br><font color='#FF0000'>"                      +active+
                            "</font><br>");     
}
list.add(s);

}}    
}catch (Throwable t) {}
return list;
/***Tender view  process end***/
}

/**returnid function for toast message****/
public String returnid(int posVal){
String  p = null;
try{
JSONObject getjson=jArray.getJSONObject(posVal);
p=getjson.getString("tender_id");
}
catch(Exception e){}
return p;
}
```

what i will do..please help..

Comment: Probably you should start a AsynTask showing a progress bar for loading. Do all the heavy stuff in a separate thread.  And in the backround method of asyntask check for a condition to be true. This condition you can set true from the thread after completing the heavy stuff.

Comment: I heard about that but dont know how..can you please provide a sample code for that...

Comment: This article is a good guide for handling things is background. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html